# How do I disable "Create content" menu item for authorized users?

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal site where authorized users are allowed to create limited types of content. I'd like them only to access the creation pages through links I've made, and not have the "Create content" link cluttering up the menu for them. However, for users with roles allowed to create more types of content I'd still like them to use the "Create content" link to access the creation pages.

I've disabled and removed the submenu items for the creation pages accessible by the average authorized user from under "Create content" in the Navigation menu, but none-the-less the link still appears for them. It seems if they can create any type of content, the link appears, even though the page is empty for them.

How can I disable the "Create content" link for the limited authorized users, but have it accessible to those with a privileged role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin/build/menu-customize/navigation and disable the "Create content" item.

**Edit:** (reflecting on comment)

If you want a menu/menu item to be available only for certain users, disable the general menu as above and create a new menu. Configure the block such that it is limited to privileged users only (in the block properties).

Comment: The key thing is disabling it for authorized users in general, but leaving it available to users with permission to create content that I've left listed under the "Create content" link. This disables it for everyone.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need to create a new block, as the new menu already showed up on the Blocks configuration page.